# Alter table on a running database

Tags: alter-table, postgresql-8.4

I am using Postgres 8.4

I need to execute an `ALTER` statement on a running database with ~4M data on the relevant table. My sql is like:

```
ALTER TABLE some_table ALTER a_row bigint;
```

Now, relevant row type is `int`

But what i wonder is data consistency, Nearly 3-4 records are written to that table and some more are being read per second.

What i need to do for avoiding data consistency and such other problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute and `ALTER TABLE` sql, table will be locked and you shouldn't have any problems except some possible performance issues in `INSERT` sqls in your case. But if you are going to do this once, there is no reason to hesitate.